# Why shared library is linked by absolute path?

Tags: c++, linker, shared, ldd

I create an application by linking the libociei.so and libcustome.so

CC -o main main.cpp ../lib/libociei.so ../lib/libcustome.so

and copy libociei.so libcustome.so to /usr/lib

then I use ldd to check library, it shows:

```
   main .....
   libcustome.so  ===>   /usr/lib/libcustome.so
   ../lib/libociei.so
```

why libociei.so is not relocated to /usr/lib/libociei.so ?

ps : ld library path is /lib:/usr/lib and I do not add ../lib to ld library path

Comment: Why didn't you use `-L` and `-l` to specify the library?

Comment: This may not help (so i'm not posting it as an answer), but you are not naming those libraries correctly and i bet they don't have sonames.  see http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux (say Ubuntu) then it is probably because you did not run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

On other systems I am not so sure.

Comment: I don't know why libcustome.so  is OK ?

Comment: That response does not make much sense? My suggestion now would be to try and clarify your question and read more about how shared objects work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use readelf -d main does the NEEDED entries have the full path?

My guess is that ldd is seeking the libraries in the default path.